# How to empty the shopping cart when a customer logs in?

Tags: magento-1.9, login, shopping-cart, customer-account

I would like to do this in Magento 1.9. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You need to hook an event. You could do this as follows.
Add the event to your module's config.xml file (app/code/local/Lpf/ModuleCookie/etc/config.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lpf_ModuleCookie>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </Lpf_ModuleCookie>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <lpf_modulecookie>
                <class>Lpf_ModuleCookie_Model</class>
            </lpf_modulecookie>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <customer_login>
                <observers>
                    <lpf_modulecookie_customer_login>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>lpf_modulecookie/observer</class>
                        <method>customerLogin</method>
                    </lpf_modulecookie_customer_login>
                </observers>
            </customer_login>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Now create a model Lpf_ModuleCookie_Model_Observer (app/code/local/Lpf/ModuleCookie/Model/Observer.php). Add a customerLogin() method to the class:

```
<?  

    class Lpf_ModuleCookie_Model_Observer
{

     /**
      * Run couple of 'php' codes after customer logs in
      *
      * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
      */
     public function customerLogin($observer)
     {
     $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();
    $items = $cart->getItems();
    $itemCount = count($items);
    if($itemCount > 1)
    {
        $i = 0;
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            $i++;
            if($i == $itemCount)
            {
                if($item->getProduct()->getId() == $productId)
                {
                    $itemId = $item->getItemId();
                    $cart->removeItem($itemId)->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            if($item->getProduct()->getId() == $productId)
            {
                try{
                    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
                    $quote->removeAllItems();
                    $quote->save();
                }catch (Exception $e)
                {
                    Mage::log('Failed to remove item from cart'.$e.'.');
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do so, you need to create a little module:

`app/code/local/DigitalPianism/Emptycart/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <DigitalPianism_Emptycart>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </DigitalPianism_Emptycart>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <class>DigitalPianism_Emptycart_Model</class>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <customer_login>
                <observer>
                    <digitalpianism_emptycart_customer_login>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>emptycart/observer</class>
                        <method>emptyCustomerCart</method>
                    </digitalpianism_emptycart_customer_login>
                </observers>
            </customer_login>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Then in `app/code/local/DigitalPianism/Emptycart/Model/Observer.php`

```
<?php

class DigitalPianism_Emptycart_Model_Observer
{
    public function emptyCustomerCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate();
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->save();
    }
}
```

**Don't forget to add the `Mage_Checkout` dependency in the `app/etc/modules/DigitalPianism_Emptycart.xml` so the quote cleaning is done after the customer quote is loaded**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <DigitalPianism_Emptycart>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends><Mage_Checkout/></depends>
        </DigitalPianism_Emptycart>
    </modules>  
</config>
```